Cutting dynamic holes into objects with an animated object
What I'm trying to do is making parts of a house transparent to see inside. However, simply deleting the geometry for every "window" i want to make is not viable. The transparent area should be dynamically adjustible. For example by masking it with another object.
A Boolean modifier does this quite well. You can cut through multiple objects with another object that can be moved accordingly.

The problem is, for a more complex scenario I would have to assign boolean modifiers with the masking object selected to every single object it's supposted to cut.
Is there a simpler way? I thought about a holdout object, but this hides everything behind it. Or maybe there is a way to hide everything that's inside a transparent object, without affecting geometry and having to apply it to every object, like the boolean?
Edit:
As suggested, I tried geometry nodes. I have no experience with those, but this is what worked:


A hidden collection containing the scene, a "controller" with a transparent material and an object with the geometry node modifier. The controller can be animated, moving the cut out in the process.


In Geometry nodes, if your target objects all belonged to, or were linked to, one collection, you could cut them all with one operation.

Thank you for this hint. I edited my post. Is this what you had in mind? It works so far for what I'm trying to do, but is there a way to keep the cut surfaces closed with the boolean node?
